# Error in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i'm developying an app by backbone but now go out the same error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'match'`

This error begins come out when i've added the call new Signupview:

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars", "models/person", "views/signupview", "text!templates/loginview.html"], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, Signupview, template) {
    var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(template),
        events: {
            "click .sign_up": "signUp_manual"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            var html = this.template();
            $('#pagina').html(this.$el.html(html)); //appendo ad el);
            return this;
        },
        signUp_manual: function () {
            console.log("signup");
            new Signupview();
        }
        //inserire funzione per log-in
    });
    return LoginView;
});
```

And here the Signupview:

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars", "text!templates/signup.html"], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, template) {
    var Signupview = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(template),
        events: {},
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            var html = this.template();
            $('#pagina').html(this.$el.html(html)); //appendo ad el);
            return this;
        }
    });
    return Signupview;
});
```

Comment: The error obviously does not stem from the posted code. Please look up its line number, and present us the relevant code.

Comment: handlebars.js line 366

Comment: match = this._input.match(this.rules[rules[i]]);

Comment: Help me please!!I'm coming crazy!

Comment: The length of your requires and your callback params don't match. Your fifth require is models/person

Comment: Another question relating to backbone:i'm developing a social app and there are users that can signup with own username,password,name ecc.. .Must i create a model "user" that consist of username,password ecc. and send to the server (parse.com) by a function inside model user?Or i have send user info directly without create model?

Comment: It will be good if you create a model for that. B/C we may need some validation there that we do in validate() function in model. This will make sure separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from this line,

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars", "models/person", "views/signupview", "text!templates/loginview.html"], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, PersonModel, Signupview, template) {
    //your code
});
```

where you missed PersonModel argument in the callback function